# Stack on Windows - where is it?

Tags: c++, c, windows, stack, kernel

I'm a bit confused on where an exe stack is located.. I know that the CRT before the program runs initializes the heap by allocating an amount of heap (which in turn is allocated by the OS that allocates pages), but where's the stack? Is it on a page too? Or is it shared by all programs in user mode (ring3) by using a ring3 descriptor on the GDT (I think not but I'm not sure) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows will reserve a contiguous area of virtual memory (1MB by default) per thread. It then commits a few top-most pages of that memory region and marks a couple below that as guard pages.  As the thread's stack grows downward, if a guard page is accessed an exception occurs and Windows commits the guard page and marks pages below that as guard.

You can explore this behavior with the excellent [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) utility [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533).  Below is a snippet from that tool:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Each thread is given its own stack. It's just a chunk of memory allocated for that purpose.

All memory is allocated in pages, including the stack (On Windows, I believe the stack defaults to 1MB, so it would span a number of pages, given that most memory pages are 4KB.)

But it's really just a chunk of memory pointed to by the stack pointer register.

Comment: The stack is initialized when the thread get created, so for a single threaded application, the stack for the main thread is created when application starts up, should this also be done by crt?

Comment: The crt cannot do it - it may not be a C program!  Even if it is, the stack must be set up before the crt is run else the crt would be unable to use the stack, ie. it would be unable to use any auto variables, parameters or make any function calls.  The Windows OS loader sets up the initial stack, instructed by the data in the EXE/DLL/SYS/whatever PE header.

Answer (score 1):

Each program in Windows is a process. Processes generally do not share their memories between one another.

Sharing and not sharing is the question of how each process's virtual address space maps onto the physical memory.

If two processes have portions of their address spaces mapped onto the same pages of the physical memory, that memory is effectively shared by them, and each process can read and possibly write it and observe writes of the other process.

There's very little sense in sharing the stack memory and so every process has got its own stack. Actually, processes are more like containers. The entities that execute code and use the stack are threads. There's at least one thread in every process. Threads have their own stacks, but since threads of a process are in the same virtual address space, they can access each others stacks. Sometimes it's useful to share on-stack data between threads, but it should be done carefully so as not to corrupt thread states and cause hangs or crashes.